# Bomblab Phase 4

Tags: assembly, x86

Working on dissembled code, I understand that my second input has to be between 2 and 4, I need help working through how to get my first input. The input is two ints

```
   0x0000000000401128 <+4>: lea    rcx,[rsp+0x14]
   0x000000000040112d <+9>: lea    rdx,[rsp+0x10]
   0x0000000000401132 <+14>:    mov    esi,0x40271a
   0x0000000000401137 <+19>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000000000040113c <+24>:    call   0x400b80 <sscanf@plt>
   0x0000000000401141 <+29>:    cmp    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000401144 <+32>:    jne    0x401154 <phase_4+48>
   0x0000000000401146 <+34>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x14]
   0x000000000040114a <+38>:    cmp    eax,0x1
   0x000000000040114d <+41>:    jle    0x401154 <phase_4+48>
   0x000000000040114f <+43>:    cmp    eax,0x4
   0x0000000000401152 <+46>:    jle    0x401159 <phase_4+53>
   0x0000000000401154 <+48>:    call   0x401432 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401159 <+53>:    mov    esi,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x14]
   0x000000000040115d <+57>:    mov    edi,0x5
   0x0000000000401162 <+62>:    call   0x400e70 <func4>
   0x0000000000401167 <+67>:    cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
   0x000000000040116b <+71>:    je     0x401172 <phase_4+78>
   0x000000000040116d <+73>:    call   0x401432 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401172 <+78>:    add    rsp,0x18
   0x0000000000401176 <+82>:    ret
```

Function 4

```
x0000000000400e70 <+0>: mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x18],rbx
   0x0000000000400e75 <+5>: mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rbp
   0x0000000000400e7a <+10>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x8],r12
   0x0000000000400e7f <+15>:    sub    rsp,0x18
   0x0000000000400e83 <+19>:    mov    ebp,edi
   0x0000000000400e85 <+21>:    mov    r12d,esi
   0x0000000000400e88 <+24>:    test   edi,edi
   0x0000000000400e8a <+26>:    jg     0x400e94 <func4+36>
   0x0000000000400e8c <+28>:    mov    r12d,0x0
   0x0000000000400e92 <+34>:    jmp    0x400eb7 <func4+71>
   0x0000000000400e94 <+36>:    cmp    edi,0x1
   0x0000000000400e97 <+39>:    je     0x400eb7 <func4+71>
   0x0000000000400e99 <+41>:    lea    edi,[rbp-0x1]
   0x0000000000400e9c <+44>:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
   0x0000000000400ea0 <+48>:    call   0x400e70 <func4>
   0x0000000000400ea5 <+53>:    mov    ebx,eax
   0x0000000000400ea7 <+55>:    lea    edi,[rbp-0x2]
   0x0000000000400eaa <+58>:    mov    esi,r12d
   0x0000000000400ead <+61>:    call   0x400e70 <func4>
   0x0000000000400eb2 <+66>:    add    eax,ebx
   0x0000000000400eb4 <+68>:    add    r12d,eax
   0x0000000000400eb7 <+71>:    mov    eax,r12d
   0x0000000000400eba <+74>:    mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rsp]
   0x0000000000400ebe <+78>:    mov    rbp,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x0000000000400ec3 <+83>:    mov    r12,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
   0x0000000000400ec8 <+88>:    add    rsp,0x18
   0x0000000000400ecc <+92>:    ret
```

I know that it's a recursive function and everything, however, I can't quite figure out what func4 is doing, even after getting the info on all registers throughout every step.

Comment: If you've already done enough reverse engineering to figure some stuff out, include your notes in the question (e.g. as comments in the asm about what high-level stuff is being implemented by groups of instructions) so readers don't have to start from scratch working out what this code does.

Comment: @Michael `test` **does** update `OF`. As per the instruction set reference: _"The OF and CF flags are set to 0."_

Comment: So first input of phase_4 should be 33 and (second input of phase_4)? If x/d $rsp+0x10 is 33? @Jester